# Settings input text become uppercase in database automatically

Tags: php, mysql

May I know how can I make the input text become UPPERCASE automatically in MySQL database although I filled in the form with lowercase? I only know how to make the text become uppercase in text field.

Here's my code for text field:

1. Text Field for poly_code
2. Text Field for poly_name

Comment: For this you can while saving the data in the field use this MySQL string function "UPPER" in your query. For more information you can have look [here(MySQL string functions)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: You specifically asked about doing this through phpMyAdmin, but then you show some HTML code. Do you really want to do this in phpMyAdmin, the graphical administrative tool to work with a MySQL database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the PHP file, where the HTML data will go to, after submitting.
There you can use the `strtoupper` method:

```
$poly_code = strtoupper($_POST['poly_code']);
$poly_name = strtoupper($_POST['poly_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done while inserting the data into the table using UPPER. See example below

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
   VALUES (UPPER('POLY_NAME'));
```